# Routes are accessible with index.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing this issue in Laravel. I have this route: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/latest-news." If I put "index.php" at the beginning of the route like this: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php/latest-news," it still works. Please help. Thanks

It should return 404 not found page if route is accessed with "index.php" in the beginning of the route.

Comment: it should return a 302 to the link without index.php

Comment: @ayazBAM If your issue is resolved, kindly mark the answer as complete (using the checkmark) :)

Comment: Thanks for your time I am working on multiple projects, so I will try this later; if it works, I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by modifying the `.htaccess` file in your project's public directory. By default`.htaccess` file is configured to remove the `index.php` from the URL. You can modify it to return a 404 response if `index.php` is present in the URL.

Here's how you can modify the `.htaccess` file:

1. Navigate to your Laravel project's `public` directory.
2. Open the `.htaccess` file in a text editor.

Locate the following section:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Replace it with the following code to return a 404 response if `index.php` is present in the URL:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Return 404 for URLs starting with index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Save the changes to the `.htaccess` file.

Now, when you access a URL with `index.php` at the beginning, it should return a 404 Not Found response. For example, accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php/latest-news` should result in a 404 error. However, accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/latest-news` should work as usual.